# Error al enviar formulario laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

Buenas tardes tengo el siguiente error tengo dos tablas relacionadas una usuarios y la otra publicaciones al yo rellenar mi formulario de crear publicacion me sale el siguiente error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id_usuario' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `Publicacion` (`foto`, `descripcion`, `id_usuario`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (images/featureds/1621722112-violence portrays fear of other people's ideas and little faith in one's own.jpg, hola, ?, 2021-05-22 22:21:52, 2021-05-22 22:21:52))
```

esta es mi migracion de publicaciones

```
        Schema::create('publicacion', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('descripcion');
        $table->string('foto');
        $table->bigInteger('id_usuario')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('id_usuario')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Esta es mi migracion de usuarios es creada por laravel brezze

```
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

[image: asi es como estan mis tablas]

Aqui es como guardo el form

```
        $newPost = new Publicacion();


    if( $request->hasFile('foto') ) {
        $file = $request->file('foto');
        $destinationPath = 'images/featureds/';
        $filename = time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $uploadSuccess = $request->file('foto')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
        $newPost->foto = $destinationPath . $filename;
    }

    $newPost->descripcion = $request->descripcion;
    $newPost->id_usuario = $request->id_usuario;


    $newPost->save();

    return redirect()->back();
```

Recalco esto pasa cuando creo un post. Gracias espero su ayuda

Comment: public function store(Request $request)  no te entiendo muy bien me puedes contestar mi pregunta @BetaM

Comment: si si lo trae esa es mi otra tabla

Comment: Edita y muestranos por favor de donde llega ese id_usuario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id_usuario' cannot be null

Por reglas de integridad tu base de datos no te permite insertar un `id_usuario` que no existe o `null` que es justo lo que haces aquí en el `?`.

```sql
values (images/featureds/..., hola, ?, 2021-05-22 22:21:52, 2021-05-22 22:21:52)
```

Cambia el signo de interrogación por un `id_usuario` válido.

> ### 13.1.20.5 FOREIGN KEY Constraints
>
> MySQL supports foreign keys, which permit cross-referencing related data across tables, and foreign key constraints, which help keep the related data consistent.
> A foreign key relationship involves a parent table that holds the initial column values, and a child table with column values that reference the parent column values. A foreign key constraint is defined on the child table.
> [FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)